# Routing Issue Between Interfaces under CentOS7/Firewalld

Tags: networking, routing, centos-7, firewalld

I use a Linux PC as my Internet gateway; it's running a fresh installation of CentOS 7 x64. I have one subnet (192.168.2.0/24) which is my regular Home network, and I have a second, separate subnet (192.168.3.0/24) for use by guests. As you would expect, the intent is to allow my guests to access the Internet without being able to access any of the hosts on my regular Home network.

To that end, the gateway PC has 3 physical Ethernet interfaces installed:

- enp0s25 (zone=external): masqueraded connection to the Internet;
  address assigned via DHCP from my ISP
- enp4s2 (zone=internal):       Attached to my Home subnet; static
  address 192.168.2.254       (192.168.2.0/24)
- enp4s0 (zone=guest):    Attached to my Guest subnet;    static
  address 192.168.3.254    (192.168.3.0/24)

Attached to this Guest subnet is a separate WiFi AP to provide Guest WiFi access to the Internet. The Guest AP has a static address 192.168.3.3.

The gateway PC provides a DHCP server for both the Internal (192.168.2.0/24) and Guest (192.168.3.0/24) subnets as well as a caching DNS server.

I can connect a WiFi client to this AP, receive a DHCP address assignment from the CentOS box, and connect to hosts on the Internet. I cannot reach any hosts on the Internal subnet. 
From hosts on the Internal network I can connect to the gateway PC and out to the Internet. I can ping the 192.168.3.254 interface on the gateway but nothing on the Guest network behind it. 
If I log onto the gateway PC via SSH I can connect to everything on both subnets.

So far all of this is the desired behavior. Now for the problem:

Occasionally I may need to connect to the Guest WiFi AP at 192.168.3.3 for maintenance purposes. Currently I can connect to the Guest AP using WiFi and log into the Admin page that way, but it would be more convenient to be able to reach the admin page from my desktop PC on the Internal subnet. Obviously I would prefer to keep this connectivity one-way, i.e. hosts on Internal subnet can connect to hosts on Guest subnet but not vice-versa. Is there a way to allow this? I've tried moving the interfaces around to different zones, adding rich rules, adding direct forwarding rules, etc. but nothing I have tried has worked. What am I missing?

Here are my firewalld zones and kernel routing table:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
internal
  interfaces: enp4s2
external
  interfaces: enp0s25
public
  interfaces: enp4s0

# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp4s0
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client dns dhcp mdns http https ntp smtp
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp4s2
  sources:
  services: ssh mdns samba-client dhcpv6-client dns http https mysql ntp pop3s smtp icecast pop3 samba dhcp
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --zone=external --list-all
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s25
  sources:
  services: ssh openvpn
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# ip route show
default via 72.211.220.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp metric 102
72.211.220.0/22 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src <redacted> metric 102
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp4s2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.254 metric 101
192.168.3.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.254 metric 100
```

And here is the output of iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_external  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_guest  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_external  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_guest  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_external (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_external_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_external_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_external_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_external_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_external_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_external_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_guest (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_guest_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_guest_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_guest_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_guest_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_guest_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_guest_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_internal (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_trusted (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_trusted_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_trusted_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_trusted_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_trusted_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_trusted_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_trusted_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_external (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_external_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_external_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_external_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_external_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain FWDO_external_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_external_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_guest (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_guest_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_guest_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_guest_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_guest_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_guest_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_guest_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_internal (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_trusted (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_trusted_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_trusted_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_trusted_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_trusted_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_trusted_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_trusted_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_internal  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_external  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_guest   all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_external (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_external_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_external_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_external_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_external_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn ctstate NEW

Chain IN_external_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_external_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_guest (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_guest_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_guest_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_guest_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_guest_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW

Chain IN_guest_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_guest_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_internal (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_internal_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_internal_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_internal_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_internal_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:irdmi ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:vcom-tunnel ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps ctstate NEW

Chain IN_internal_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_internal_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_trusted (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_trusted_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_trusted_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_trusted_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_trusted_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_trusted_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_trusted_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```